# Implementing destructor of an n-ary tree

Tags: c++, tree, destructor

I have been dealing with n-ary trees for a while. Well now I need to write the destruction part for it. What I did is a created a global stack and a helper function. The idea was when the program finishes, the destructor will be called. And inside the destructor I call my helper function, where my helper function places all nodes to be deleted in the stack. Later I delete the nodes stored in the stack one by one.

The problem is when I run valgrind to check memory freed, it gives some suppressed error and it seems as if not all tree is deleted.

```
Node* destroy_des(Node* ptr)
{
    if(ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else 
       des.push(ptr);

    for(Node *pChild=ptr->getFirstChild(); pChild!=NULL;  pChild=pChild->getNextSibling())
    {
         Node *pTarget = destroy_des(pChild);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

HERE the name of the stack is 'des', and in the helper function the root is passed as a parameter

```
TREE :: ~TREE()
 {
    destroy_des(root);   

   while( !des.empty())
   {    
        Node* temp = des.top();
        des.pop();
        temp->setNextSibling(NULL);
        temp->setParent(NULL);
        temp->setFirstChild(NULL);
        delete temp;
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
 ==26349== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
 ==26349==    at 0x40348B: destroy_des(Node*) (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x40346C: destroy_des(Node*) (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x40346C: destroy_des(Node*) (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x414EED: TREE::~TREE() (in        /home/bs04/e1848357/Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x414FD4: main (in /home/bs04/e1848357/Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349== 
 ==26349== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
 ==26349==    at 0x40348B: destroy_des(Node*) (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x40346C: destroy_des(Node*) (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x414EED: TREE::~TREE() (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x414FD4: main (in Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349== 
 ==26349== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
 ==26349==    at 0x40348B: destroy_des(Node*) (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x414EED: TREE::~TREE() (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349==    by 0x414FD4: main (in /Desktop/hw3/a.out)
 ==26349== 
 ==26349== 
 ==26349== HEAP SUMMARY:
 ==26349==     in use at exit: 165 bytes in 10 blocks
 ==26349==   total heap usage: 716 allocs, 706 frees, 46,064 bytes allocated
 ==26349== 
 ==26349== LEAK SUMMARY:
 ==26349==    definitely lost: 55 bytes in 6 blocks
 ==26349==    indirectly lost: 110 bytes in 4 blocks
 ==26349==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==26349==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==26349==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
 ==26349== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
 ==26349== 
 ==26349== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
 ==26349== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
 ==26349== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: I don't see any `delete` in the `destroy_des` function. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Actually I do not delete them in the 'destroy_des' function. I just place the nodes to be deleted there and I delete the nodes in the destructor

Comment: Could you add the valgrind error message?

Comment: Try to write "delete pTarget" after Node *pTarget = destroy_des(pChild);

Comment: @SGrebenkin That'd delete NULL, which will have no effect (destroy_des always returns NULL, so it should probably just be a void method and return nothing)

Comment: oops. put it after for cycle. before return NULL then. this will do simple greedy DFS deletion.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you are right.

Comment: @user2878007 How are you initializing your nodes when before adding them to the tree? Also, compiling your code with `-g` should give better info on line numbers etc. for the warnings.

Comment: By creating the node, like: Node *ptr = new Node("name");  Note that the code does not have any flaw during the execution, or any warning. I have checked it well.